# I have a 404 error in my console when i click a function button

Tags: javascript, html, django, fetch

I have a simple add and remove button for a cart, but whenever i click on the button, i get an error in the console, please bear in mind, i a newbie:

```
cart.js:25 POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/update_item/ 404 (Not Found)
updateUserOrder @ cart.js:25
(anonymous) @ cart.js:14
127.0.0.1/:1 Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
```

**And this is the error i get in my terminal:**

```
Not Found: /update_item/
```

I strongly feel this is the problem, as the fetch is not recognizing update_item in views.py

**This is the code in cart.js:**

```
function updateOrder (ticketId, action){
console.log('User is logged in, sending data..')

var url = '/update_item/'

fetch(url, {
    method:'POST',
    headers:{
        'Content-Type':'application/json',
        'X-CSRFToken': csrftoken,
    },
    body:JSON.stringify({'ticketId': ticketId, 'action':action})
})

.then((response) =>{
    return response.json()
})
.then((data) =>{
    console.log('data:', data)
    location.reload()
})
```

}

**This is my views.py code:**

```
def updateItem(request):
data = json.loads(request.body)
ticketId = data['ticketId']
action = data['action']

print('Action:', action)
print('ticketId:', ticketId)


customer = request.user.customer
ticket = Ticket.objects.get(id=ticketId)
order, created = Order.objects.get_or_create(customer=customer, complete=False)

orderItem, created = OrderItem.objects.get_or_create(order=order, ticket=ticket)

if action == 'add':
    orderItem.quantity = (orderItem.quantity + 1)
elif action == 'remove':
    orderItem.quantity = (orderItem.quantity - 1)

orderItem.save()

if orderItem.quantity <= 0:
    orderItem.delete()

return JsonResponse('Item was added', safe=False)
```

Comment: Where is the rest of your URL?

Comment: This is it      path('checkout/', views.checkout, name="checkout"),

 path('update_item/', views.updateItem, name="update_item"),

Comment: If you are not going to use the Json properly in the response but to console.log a success message, probably the straigth forward way: not return a Jsonresponse from views and use a string in JS to return that messagge.

Comment: I have that so that i know it worked. But it not working

Answer (score 1):

JsonResponse by default expect to return a Json Dict. Using: safe=False you override this behavior telling that it's OK to return a non dict object.

Your problem is that in this line:

```js
    return response.json()
```

Your JS code wait as well for a dict.

So you have to pass a JsonDict in the response and JS will be able to parse it

Comment: Thank you for your response, this is what i have:`return JsonResponse('Item was added', safe=False)` please what do you recommend i do?

Comment: As I said response.json wait for a dictionnary not a string. like {'status':'ok'} this is a json dictionnary